# Unable to start Android 4.4 AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-4.4-kitkat

I guess the title is self explanatory. 
I created a AVD - 
Target - android-19
Device - 5.4" FWVGA
Memory => RAM - 768 and VM Heap - 32
Internal Storage - 200

But I am not able to start it.

I copied the platform/android-19 folder from another laptop and also the android-19 system image. But I dont think that should be a problem. I can see the android-19 option in the drop-down but the AVD is not getting started.

Here is the screenshot while creating the AVD - 
[image]

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: please give the error log

Comment: @Amith - there is no error log. AVD screen is just blank. I am waiting for the past 15 mins for something to happen.

Comment: did you noticed something like unable to allocate memmory

Comment: @yashdosi did you also try to use the UI app for creating the AVD and even there it didn't work?

Comment: @Amith - yes that happened but then I deleted that AVD. And created a new one with less RAM(768 - earlier it was 1024) and Heap(32). For this AVD, I could not see any errors.

Comment: @androiddeveloper - i am using the eclipse's AVD Manager to create/start/delete AVDs.

Comment: Restart your s/m if still that occurs please drop a comment

Comment: @yashdosi which CPU architecture did you use , and did you enable the GPU feature too? i think that if you use an Intel architecture and/or GPU feature, it can cause problems. try using the ARM architecture and disable the GPU feature. can you please show a screenshot of the creation of the profile ?

Comment: @yashdosi - As stated in my below response, you must have checked the Emulation Options as Snapshot. Try that

Comment: @Gem_Ram - still no luck! I tried restarting my laptop as well.

Comment: @Amith - restarted my system as well. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please delete the existing AVD and create a new as per the image instructions. I've done it for you at my side newly with your requirement and it is up well as indicated in the image.

I believe you've updated your SDK through SDK manager as the latest is 4.4.2, if not, do that as well and check

All the Best !

Answer (score 1):

[image]
I'm attaching a screenshot for your reference:

1. CPU / ABI --> as per your available resource either Intel / ARM
2. Keep the RAM size to 512MB as 768MB is the maximum allowable and check if it works
3. Emulator options --> Check Snapshot feature
4. SD Card ---> 100MB is enough

Then start the emulator AVD. It should be up and running. If problems, try to restart the eclipse and re-start the AVD Emulator. sometimes, restarting really helps...